# How to create a text file in local drive using vf page or Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can anybody help me,

I want to create a text file in Local Drive or File server using salesforce APEX class or VF Page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Salesforce have no access to your local drive because it is an cloud-application.

What you can do: create a visualforce page and render it as a text file using an [`contentType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) attribute:

```
contentType="text/plain#test.txt"
```

The user could then download a text file to the local drive manually.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer the below link:

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/07/how-to-download-visualforce-page-as.html

**Sample Code:**

**Visualforce page:**

```
<apex:page controller="Sample" sidebar="false" action="{!fetch}" contentType="text/plain/#emp.txt" cache="false">
Employee Number : {!emp.Name}
Employee Name : {!emp.Employee_Name__c}
City : {!emp.City__c}
Email : {!emp.Email__c}
Description : {!emp.Description__c}
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class Sample
{   
    public String empId;
    public Employee__c emp {get;set;}

    public Sample()
    {

    }

    public void fetch()
    {
        empId = Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('eid');
        emp = [SELECT Name, Employee_Name__c, City__c, State__c, Email__c, Description__c FROM Employee__c WHERE ID =: empId];
    }    

}
```